# Which potentials in real life are separable in variables?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy, integrable-systems

We usually see in 3d potential problems, that we consider potential to be separable as a sum of three independent one dimensional like potential, for all three variables, i.e

$$V(x, y, z)=V(x)+V(y)+V(z).$$

Does this happen for any real potential we deal with in real life?

Comment: The central potential leads to separable solutions in spherical coordinates.

Comment: This isn't what separable means - separable would be $V(x,y,z) = X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$. This is very common, and it is useful because it means $\frac{1}{V}\frac{d}{dx_i}V = \frac{1}{X_i(x_i)}\frac{dX_i(x_i)}{dx_i}$